# (gcloud.functions.deploy) unrecognized arguments: --runtime did you mean --timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Following this [Google OCR Tutorial, deploying functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr#deploying_the_functions), **Node.js** step 1 To deploy the image processing function with a Cloud Storage trigger, run the following command in the app directory:

```
gcloud functions deploy ocr-extract --runtime nodejs6 --trigger-bucket My_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME --entry-point MyprocessImage
```

getting

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) unrecognized arguments:   --runtime
>   (did you mean '--timeout'?)

Node version 10
VS Code 1.17.2
Windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As of Aug 28th, 2018 and the release of the Cloud SDK version 214.0.0, the `--runtime` flag has been promoted to GA and the `beta` command isn't needed anymore.

---

The `--runtime` flag was [added in Cloud SDK version 208.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#cloud_functions_1), in beta only so far. I've requested to update the tutorial you linked in the documentation.

Check that you have Cloud SDK >= 208.0.0 and run this command instead:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy ocr-extract --runtime nodejs6 --trigger-bucket My_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME --entry-point MyprocessImage
```

Comment: after updating my gcloud sdk from 207 to 211.0.0, type in this `gcloud functions deploy ocr-extract --runtime nodejs6 --trigger-bucket xyz_image_bucketname --entry-point processImage` got **ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) unrecognized arguments:
  --runtime (did you mean '--timeout'?)
  nodejs6**

Comment: Note that you need to use gcloud beta functions... for the moment

Comment: Ran with `beta` it installed the missing beta component and asked me to rerun the same command. Reran the same cmd got **(gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) unrecognized arguments: processImage**.

Answer (score 3):

I had a [default installation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install#installation_options) with `apt-get` and I can't figure out how to 1. upgrade it and 2. stop "You cannot perform this action because the Cloud SDK component manager is managed by an external package manager" error.

So I removed it completely with

```
sudo apt-get remove google-cloud-sdk
```

and installed interactivelly

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

now all beta commands work fine